# Adding UINavigationController inside splitViewController in iPad

Tags: ios, ipad, uinavigationcontroller, uisplitviewcontroller

I am using a splitViewController, My Detail View has a navigationController as a parent.

I have added it this  way

My app is universal.So I have created different xibs for both iphone and ipad.

```
_moreOptions = [[MoreOptionsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MoreOptionsViewController" bundle:nil];

_settingsView = [[SettingsViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"SettingsViewController_iPad" bundle:nil];

UINavigationController *navController = [[UINavigationController alloc]initWithRootViewController:_settingsView];

_moreOptions.settigsView = _settingsView;

self.splitViewController3 = [[UISplitViewController alloc]init];
// self.splitViewController3.title = @"More";
self.splitViewController3.delegate = _settingsView;
self.splitViewController3.viewControllers = @[_moreOptions, navController];
```

SettingsViewController has UITableView inside it. So the problem which i m facing is that , My Detail is not filling the full height on iPad, here is the screen shot [image]

You can see the dark patch at bottom and this is my question of concern,

Answer (score 2, accepted):

---

EDIT: I think I've found a fix, apply this to the UISplitViewController:

```
[splitVC setExtendedLayoutIncludesOpaqueBars:YES];
```

This property is iOS 7 only and seems to solve the problem. Look at the methods that replace `-wantsFullscreenLayout:` in UIViewController.h.

---

I'm having the same problem -- if I build on iOS 5 or 6, it works fine, the gap isn't there. Could it be an iOS 7 bug? If so, it's a particularly inconvenient one. Still searching for a workaround.

As far as I can tell from the current documentation, we're performing the correct steps:
(see "Adding a Navigation Controller to a Tab Bar Interface")
https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/WindowsViews/Conceptual/ViewControllerCatalog/Chapters/CombiningViewControllers.html